# How to create a zip archive with files and attach it to a zip archive?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have a number of files that need to be grouped into archives, and all these archives need to be put into the archive.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    foreach (var (day, _messages) in messages.GroupBy(x => x.Date).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList()))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            using (var archiveByDay = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (var message in _messages)
                {
                    var fileInArchive = archiveByDay.CreateEntry($"{message.FileName}", CompressionLevel.Fastest);

                    var renderer = XmlHelper.SerializeWin1251(message);

                    using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
                    {
                        using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(renderer.ToArray()))
                        {
                            fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

           ///How add archiveByDay to archive
        }
    }
}
```

At this point i'm stuck

Comment: There isn't really a difference between a file and a archive. If you know how to archive files, than you know how to archive archives because they are just files with a fancy name. So what is your problem actually?

Comment: Do I need to unpack the internal archive in order to add it to the archive level above?

Comment: Depends what your goal is. Do you want to have the archives in the "parent" archive or do you want to have the content of the archives in the "parent" archive?

Comment: Archives in the parent archive

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?  What doesn't compile/work correctly, and why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Untested code, basically just to demonstrate the idea behind it)

Try the following:

```
//create the parent archive at the top of the loop
//with the given code it would have been just 1 archive in 1 archive
//now it can be many archives in 1 archive
//write the archive to file system instead of in memory
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(File.Create("C:\\test\\test.zip"), ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    foreach (var (day, _messages) in messages.GroupBy(x => x.Date).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList()))
    {
        //move the memorystrem to the inner loop
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archiveByDay = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (var message in _messages)
                {
                    var fileInArchive = archiveByDay.CreateEntry($"{message.FileName}", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                    var renderer = XmlHelper.SerializeWin1251(message);

                    using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
                    using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(renderer.ToArray()))
                        fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                }
            }

            //flush and set position to 0 enable reading the content that got written to the memory stream
            memoryStream.Flush();
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            //createentry for the parent archive and write the memory stream to it
            var fileInParentArchive = archive.CreateEntry($"{Guid.NewGuid():D}", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
            using (var entryStream = fileInParentArchive.Open())
            using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray()))
                fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
        }
    }
}
```